# How to resolve ObjectNotFoundException?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm getting ObjectNotFoundException.how to resolve this exception?

```
org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [org.sampleproject.tool.assessment.data.dao.assessment.SectionData#1822]
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl$1.handleEntityNotFound(SessionFactoryImpl.java:386)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:879)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:796)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:789)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$3.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:569)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:419)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.load(HibernateTemplate.java:563)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.load(HibernateTemplate.java:557)
```

Comment: Could you post the code that is causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have relations in your data structure?

1. Imagine two tables: *people & address*
2. You have two objects that represent those tables: Person & Address
3. Person **has a** Address, therefore table *people* contains column address
   which referrers to primary key in *address* table.
   Now imagine in table *people* you have an address which doesn’t exist in *address* table itself, in your case *people* table contains an address with ID -  #1822, but the record is not in the *address* table.

**Quick fix:**

- Insert a record to the *address* table with this ID #1822

  OR
- Delete address record with this ID - #1822 from *people* table

Answer (score 0):

At first check your keys - if given key exists in the DB?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing some date in the DB. 
If you really want to ignore it, try annotating the attribute with:

```
@NotFound( action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE )
```

or if you are using XML, something like this:

```
<xxx-to-yyy ... not-found="ignore" />
```

Comment: I'm not using not-found="ignore".